# How to reverse the polarity of a DC brushless hobby motor?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, reverse-polarity

How can I reverse a motor safely that draws about 70 A on 4 s (14.8 V), and additionally how do ESCs (Electronic Speed Controller) that have this capability built into them do it?

Comment: Add a data sheet link to the motor please.

Comment: Brushless motors are three phase synchronous motors, the ESC is a three phase inverter. To change the direction of rotation they just change the order of rotation of the phases. The feature comes for free from the way a brushless ESC operates.

Comment: @Andyaka there is no datasheet but it is just a standard brushless DC motor that came with my plane. It is called a t-motor as2308 2600kv if that helps

Comment: https://store.tmotor.com/goods-936-AS2308+Long+Shaft.html Peak Current (180s): 29A

Answer (score 1):

For permanent reversal, swap any two of the three wires between the DC brushless motor and the motor driver.

A brushless motor driver that can reverse direction on the fly effectively does this by changing the phasing of the waveforms being sent down the three wires.

Comment: This would be temporary and done automatically. Would it be possible to DIY this?

Comment: @wandyrge Yes. You just swap the connections. Unsure what you mean by "automatically" though.

Comment: I meant not needed to be physically swapped by me but instead done using some sort of relay or switch

Comment: You can do it with relays.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: It's trivial. Just use DPDT relays.

Answer (score 0):

R/C airplane DC brushless motors and inverters are designed for single-direction operation, for obvious reasons - there is no use to supporting reverse direction on an airplane, so why compromise optimization and add cost?

You will need to consult with the motor manufacturer on whether this motor can be efficiently or practicably reversed. Depending on its design, reversing may be impractical or inefficient (e.g. the motor may rapidly overheat if run in reverse, so it may be suitable only for reverse on an R/C car, scooter, power chair, boat, etc. that would spend only seconds in reverse.  So not a model train or gantry crane, where it would spend 50% of its time in reverse).

If you get the greenlight from the motor manufacturer, or a more suitable motor, then you will need a different inverter (ESC) capable of reversing under electronic/soft control.  That's really not a problem technologically. Even the aircraft ESC has the hardware to do it, it would just need its software enhanced somewhat.

Comment: "You will need to consult with the motor manufacturer" The OP already said it's a no-name motor.  Those things are all made to the same basic design, and can be driven forward as easily as backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Find an RC car ESC that's designed for operation in reverse.  Note that you'll need a matching motor -- cars need torque all the way down to zero RPM, and that means the ESC will need a motor with a position sensor output.